# Within grid background image affected by content

Tags: css, css-grid

This is kinda trickt to explain, but I got a nested grid, the grid inside the grid looks lite this:

```
.footer {
    grid-area: footer;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

.bottomdiv {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 2;
    text-align: center;
}

.leftdiv {
    background-image: url("../images/logo-sbbq4.png");
    opacity : 0.2;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 20% 100%;
    background-position: -60px 0px;
}

.contactlogo {
    font-family: Neucha;
    font-size: 4vw;
    color: #000;
    margin: 30% 4vw;
}
```

I got two problems, first one is probably easy, as you can see I want the bottomdiv to span across the 4 by 4 grid bottom.

The real problem I got is the leftdiv.
I have a backgroud image the I want to place a text above.
The image is placed and all is well but when I try to add the text the margin affects the image - I have placed it under due to CSS Cascadig nature but the didnt help.

The html looks like this:

```
<div class="footer" id="kontakt">
      <div class="leftdiv contactlogo">
        My BBQclass
      </div>
      <div class="rightdiv contacttext">
        <ul>
          <li>Telefon: 245213654</li>
          <li>E-post: me@inter.net</li>
          <li>Postgiro: 784512-22</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="bottomdiv ustext">Event, butiksevent, personalfester, fester och grillkurser. Kan även göra restaurang-gästspel med burgarna på begäran.</div>
    </div>
```

So here is my noobish problem... wanting your excellent help.

Comment: A demo of the actual problem here is required

Comment: If you don't put effort in your question, people won't put effort in the answer :-) try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).